# In a java restful json webservice if image upadated ,that updated image didnot reflect on client side?

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I wrote json based web-service in Java ,to send images to android and iphone apps .I have used file system to store those images , whenever i add new images in directory when web service is running ,mobile side didn't get that updated image.But when i run my web-service again it works images are seen on client side .Is there any way so that without running the project client side will get the updated images.

```
  if (rootDirectory.isDirectory()) {

            //root directory has the path

           FileEntry rootentry=new FileEntry(rootDirectory);//change by 
            rootentry.refresh(rootDirectory); // to refresh rootdirectory

            File childDirectories[] = rootDirectory.listFiles();

            //fetch child directories 
            rootDirectory.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < childDirectories.length; i++) {
                //File f1 = new File(path + "/" + childDirectories[i]);


                File dir = childDirectories[i];


                    File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();//images in child directory

                    System.out.println("FIle list "+filelist.toString());

                    category = new JSONObject();

                    categoryImg_Arr = new JSONArray();

                    for (int k = 0; k < filelist.length; k++) {
                        categoryImg = new JSONObject();
                        File img = filelist[k];
```

Comment: Please tell us more details. What is your code of the server in short?

Comment: In this web service , I am sending five parameters like thumb image and main image. for that i set the path of parent folder.Do you require code ?

Comment: Please edit the question and add your code there.

Comment: Just tell mi how can i refresh my file system when i update any image or directory in it. directory path is there in which number of directories are present each sub directory has several images in it ..

Comment: @AmolShewale What is the path of `rootDirectory`?

Comment: /home/amols/Amol Work Task/workingTag/ShopNSave Service/Swaroop_changes_in_viewFile_8th-Oct-14/CatalogueWebServices/src/main/webapp/Images

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be a problem of caching. Can you try to disable caching in the GET request (no-cache header)?

Comment: i am getting this exception java.io.NotSerializableException: org.json.JSONObject

Comment: Add these headers when you create the response: Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0